# Entity Framework, LINQ and patterns

Tags: linq, entity-framework, design-patterns

I've started using EF and LINQ in a project and I'm trying to decide on the best approach/pattern to use. Until now I've been using a custom persistence framework that was based on DataSets and XML configuration. Basically it was a VS Custom Tool that would read the XML configuration file and the DataSets and would generate Object Oriented classes with all the necessary properties/associations/methods. This auto-generated classes then were used from the UI and I had the flexibility to expose only what the UI would need.

Now with EF and LINQ, I'm not comfortable with the idea that the UI can use directly the auto-generated classes and all the LINQ stuff. It seems that this approach would have a very tight integration between UI and the database.

So I'm looking for some pattern that would "hide" all the EF and LINQ goodies and basically limit what the UI can do. Is there any standard way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is an n-tier application.  It's not so much a pattern as an architecture.  You break your app up into 2 or more pieces, typically 3 composed of UI, business and Data.  You might implement this through other patterns such as the Facade or Repository patterns to keep a strong seperation of concerns.

You might also use a Service Layer, which could be implemented by a facade or as a web service.

You would, ideally, pass data through objects called DTO's or Data Transfer Objects, and you might adapt those DTO's by using a view model in your UI (not to be confused with MVVM which another poster erroneously mentioned.)

Beyond that, much of it depends on the type of app you're buiding.  Desktop app, server app, web app, etc..

Answer (score 0):

The pattern you're looking for is, in general, Model-View-ViewModel, or MVVM.

Here's a tutorial that seems to hit on the high points of the design pattern: http://csharperimage.jeremylikness.com/2010/04/model-view-viewmodel-mvvm-explained.html

Comment: MVVM has nothing to do with seperating your data layer from your UI.  It's a UI pattern that is similar to MVC but replaces the Controller with a ViewModel.  It's more about observing data changes and replicating those changes to other observers.  You would typically only use MVVM in something like Silverlight, or WPF (and sometimes javascript).. it has no meaning in the context of this question.

Comment: MVVM, at least my understanding of it, has to do with separating your UI and your model (whether your model comes directly from a database, in this case, or from a service call, or an XML document etc.).  Your UI has no idea of the actual model behind the ViewModel.  The ViewModel is the only thing that your UI has to care about.  I feel this would be an appropriate pattern for him to follow in this case.

Comment: That's incorrect.  The ViewModel is still a cohesive part of the UI.  It just separates the responsibility into it's own component. The model is very much known to the UI (it has to be, otherwise the UI would not be able to access it).  You can think of the ViewModel in MVVM as a "cache" of your data model of sorts, the actual data access should be done in a different layer or tier.

Comment: The ViewModel should essentially be a translation layer between the model and the view, exposing only the fields neccesary for the UI and providing translation logic from something in the model to something to be displayed by the UI, correct?

Comment: Sort of.  To some degree.  A better way to think of it is as a Model-View-Binder.  And by Binder, I mean Data binding.  It's sort of an adapter on the model that adapts the model to fit the view.  This is why it's used so heavily in WPF and Silverlight, because those technologies are heavily data binding based.

Comment: Ah, which is why we implement INotifyPropertyChanged and have ObservableCollection<T> in the ViewModel, because those are UI specific things that the model shouldn't have to worry about.